# How to only select one column and update it?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I want  to only select one column from the database then update only that one column

```
  DB::table('available_rooms')
  ->where('roomTypeID', '=', $request->session()->get('room_type'))->first()
  ->update(['isAvailable'=> 0]);
```

With this I'm getting an error

> Call to undefined method stdClass::update()

Comment: I'm getting this error Call to undefined method stdClass::update()

Comment: Do you mean this?      
 DB::table('available_rooms')
      ->where('roomTypeID', '=', $request->session()->get('room_type'))
      ->update(['isAvailable'=> 0])->first();
I'm getting this error instead Call to a member function first() on integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `limit()` method instead of `first()`:

```
DB::table('available_rooms')
  ->where('roomTypeID', '=', $request->session()->get('room_type'))->limit(1)
  ->update(['isAvailable'=> 0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Eloquent style**

Create model if you don't created:

```
AvailableRoom::where('roomTypeID', '=',  $request->session()->get('room_type'))
              ->update(['isAvailable'=> 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

**Post::where('id', $id)->update(array('title' => 'asdasd'));**